# How do you set the connection for the activewindow (EnvDTE.Window) in a VSIX extension?

Tags: ssms, vsix

I have been racking my brain trying to figure out how to set the `SQLConnection` for a `VSIX` designed for `SSMS`.  The closest I have come is to cast the active window to a SqlScriptEditorControl which has a SetConnection method.  The problem is this only seems to assign the SqlScriptEditorControl in SSMS19 and the changes that are applied don't actually change the connection in SSMS.

```
Window activeWindow = activeDocument.ActiveWindow;
SqlScriptEditorControl editorControl = activeWindow.Object as SqlScriptEditorControl;
UIConnectionInfo newInfo = getUIConnectionfromRegisteredServer(newConnection);
editorControl.SetConnection(newInfo);
```

Does anyone know how you can change the connection in VSIX and have it apply to the `activewindow` in `SSMS`?

What I'm expecting is to be able to assign the UICOnnectionInfo for the currently active window / active document in `SSMS`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `c#` code and tell me if it works for. I couldn't test because I am not having the `IDE`

```
// Get the DTE object from the Package class
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

// Subscribe to the ActiveDocumentChanged event
dte.Events.DocumentEvents.ActiveDocumentChanged += OnActiveDocumentChanged;

// Method called when the active document changes
private void OnActiveDocumentChanged(Document document)
{
    if (document is EnvDTE.Window window)
    {
        try
        {
            // Try to access the SqlScriptEditorControl
            SqlScriptEditorControl editorControl = window.Object as SqlScriptEditorControl;
            if (editorControl != null)
            {
                // Get the UIConnectionInfo for your new connection
                UIConnectionInfo newInfo = getUIConnectionfromRegisteredServer(newConnection);

                // Use the appropriate method to set the connection based on SSMS version
                if (IsNewerVersionOfSSMS())
                {
                    ((EnvDTE.SqlWindow)window).CurrentServer = newInfo.ServerName;
                }
                else
                {
                    editorControl.SetConnection(newInfo);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle any exceptions gracefully
            // Log or display an error message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking if editorControl is null does not do any good when in SSMS 18 it doesn't cast the window.Object to a SqlScriptEditor.

I'm not seeing where there is a Class for EnvDTE.SqlWindow